# What are the methods to know when the production server goes down?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shell, nginx, webserver, unicorn

We are using rails 3.1.
We are using nginx as a web-server & unicorn as application server, and also we are running some background jobs (Eg: Solr, delayed jobs, etc.) for accomplishing some tasks. 
How can we get to know when any of these servers went down? 
What are the common methods that everyone using to get the information by running some script for automatically re-run the process or to generate some mail alerts or phone alerts.

Need some assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [god](http://godrb.com/) or [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/). As rubyist I prefer `god`.